# "Uncaught TypeError: marker.getPosition is not a function" when adding Marker Clusterer to Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

i've built a Google Map with Custom Markers from a Database which works fine. The working version can be found [here](https://www.kaipai.de/map.php).

Because there will be much more markers in the future i've tried to add a marker clusterer to the map but it gives me an error in the Google Developer Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: marker.getPosition is not a function

The version which throws the error can be found [here](https://www.kaipai.de/maptest_so.php).

Here is how my maptest_so.php looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>KaiPai | Gutes Essen</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Styles -->
    <link href="assets/map.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <img src="img/logo.png" width="85" height="25" alt="KaiPai">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Startseite
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="map.php">Karte</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">Über KaiPai</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="commitement.php">Ethik & Essen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="admin/admin.php">Administration
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="map" id="map"></div>

<!-- Custom Marker Icons -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iconBase = 'https://www.kaipai.de/img/customMapIcons/';
    var icons = {
      1: {
      name: 'Backwaren',
      icon: iconBase + 'bakery.png'
      },
      2: {
      name: 'Getränke',
      icon: iconBase + 'beverages.png'
      },
      3: {
      name: 'Fisch',
      icon: iconBase + 'fish.png'
      },
      4: {
      name: 'Früchte / Obst',
      icon: iconBase + 'fruit.png'
      },
      5: {
      name: 'Fleisch',
      icon: iconBase + 'meat.png'
      },
      6: {
      name: 'Sonstiges',
      icon: iconBase + 'other.png'
      },
      7: {
      name: 'Restaurant',
      icon: iconBase + 'restaurant.png'
      },
      8: {
      name: 'Supermarkt',
      icon: iconBase + 'supermarket.png'
      }
      };

    // Google Map initialisieren
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.5508, 9.9928),
      zoom: 11,
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Marker aus XML Datei erstellen
      downloadUrl('genxml.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
          {imagePath: 'https://www.kaipai.de/img/markerClustererImages/m'});
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var CustomerID = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerID');
          var CustomerGroupID = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerGroupID');
          var CustomerName = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerName');
          var CustomerCity = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerCity');
          var CustomerCountry = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerCountry');
          var CustomerStreetName = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerStreetName');
          var CustomerStreetNumber = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerStreetNumber');
          var CustomerPostalCode = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerPostalCode');
          var CustomerPhone = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerPhone');
          var CustomerFax = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerFax');
          var CustomerMail = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerMail');
          var CustomerWeb = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerWeb');
          var CustomerDescription = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerDescription');
          var CustomerGroupName = markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerGroupName');
          var TypeName = markerElem.getAttribute('TypeName');
          var TypeID = markerElem.getAttribute('TypeID');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerLat')),
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('CustomerLng')));
          // Inhalt des InfoWindow
          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var header = document.createElement('h5');
            header.textContent = CustomerName
            infowincontent.appendChild(header);
          var street = document.createElement('text');
            street.textContent = CustomerStreetName + ' '
            infowincontent.appendChild(street);
          var number = document.createElement('text');
            number.textContent = CustomerStreetNumber
            infowincontent.appendChild(number);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var plz = document.createElement('text');
            plz.textContent = CustomerPostalCode + ' '
            infowincontent.appendChild(plz);
          var city = document.createElement('text');
            city.textContent = CustomerCity
            infowincontent.appendChild(city);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var phone = document.createElement('text');
            phone.textContent = 'Tel: ' + CustomerPhone
            infowincontent.appendChild(phone);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var fax = document.createElement('text');
            fax.textContent = 'Fax: ' + CustomerFax
            infowincontent.appendChild(fax);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var mail = document.createElement('text');
            mail.textContent = CustomerMail
            infowincontent.appendChild(mail);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var web = document.createElement('text');
            web.textContent = CustomerWeb
            infowincontent.appendChild(web);
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
          var routeLink = document.createElement('a');
          var routeLinkText = document.createTextNode("Route in Google Maps planen");
            routeLink.appendChild(routeLinkText);
            routeLink.title = 'Route in Google Maps planen';
            routeLink.target = '_blank'
            routeLink.href = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + CustomerStreetName + '+' + CustomerStreetNumber + '+' + CustomerPostalCode + '+' + CustomerCity
            infowincontent.appendChild(routeLink);
          var icon = icons[TypeID] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icons[TypeID].icon
          });

          // Marker Click Event erzeugen
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
<!-- Google Maps JavaScript API -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAUBsRd-k9I9BjQdiUmKqeQEHYBQIxUfV4&callback=initMap">
</script>
<!-- Google Maps Marker Clusterer -->
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
</script>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The Error occurs on page load and it seems to happen here:

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
          {imagePath: 'https://www.kaipai.de/img/markerClustererImages/m'

I already tried out the accepted Solution from [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968600/object-has-no-method-getposition-when-clustering-google-map-markers-api-v3) but it didn't work. I've tried to test the first answer in the same thread but i do not understand it completely.

Can anyone help me to point me in the right direction?
I'm new to the Google Maps Javascript API and Webdesign at all, so please don't mind if my question is a bit unspecific.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: You should remove the PHP tag if the question doesn't involve PHP in any way. You should also let us know _where_ and _when_ in this code it throws that error. Don't force us to search through it all and guess.

Comment: After this assignment 
`var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');`
 what is the value of your `markers` variable? Is it an array of [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) objects?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the MarkerClusterer and populating it with whatever was returned from your xml file. it needs to be populated with actual `google.maps.Marker` objects

Change your `forEach` call to a `map` and place it inside your call to create a new MarkerClusterer instance like so:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(
  map, 
  Array.prototype.map.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
    //... all your other code
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            icon: icons[TypeID].icon       
    });
    return marker;

  }
  {imagePath: 'https://www.kaipai.de/img/markerClustererImages/m'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You reported an error like Uncaught TypeError: `marker.getPosition` is not a function when in fact `marker.getPosition` cannot be seen anywhere in your code. When debugging or trying to reproduce errors, it is better to provide self-contained sample code that help your fellow developers to reproduce the problem. [Please read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
2. Your InfoWindow constructor is missing parenthesis so add them like so:

   ```
   var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   ```
3. You are passing DOM elements (Nodes to be exact) inside your MarkerClusterer when in fact you must pass in Markers object, not DOM elements. In other words you cannot expect this code to work in your markerClusterer:

   ```
   downloadUrl('genxml.php', function(data) {
     var xml = data.responseXML;
     var markers = xml.document.getElementsByTagName('marker');
   ```
4. the code you provided does not have any HTML element with a tag name marker:

   ```
   var markers = xml.document.getElementsByTagName('marker');
   ```

   Where is marker in your HTML?
5. At the end of your script you initiate the Marker constructor but then you call the method which is (I think) out of scope; once you sort your code structure, syntax errors and logic errors, see if you get any errors in the console for the marker and if necessary move your variable either in the global scope or in the same lexical scope so that it can be accessed.

Unfortunately I could not reproduce the problem in its entirety because I lacked the dependencies and other parts of your application to be more thorough... Still, the above should suffice to make it work.

Comment: The MarkerClusterer source code calls `marker.getPosition` several times and I believe that is where the error (Uncaught TypeError: `marker.getPosition`) is produced. [Take a look](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#L865)

Comment: I have already looked at your code and as I said already, you cannot pass DOM elements in the markerClusterer. Your `var markers` stores an array-like object (HTML elements or nodes) and that's not right. You got to pass in Markers objects. Beside that,  sorry I have to repeat myself, your code has syntax and logic bugs. See my previous comment please.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't look like @rolle78hh is passing in an array of `Marker` objects to the `MarkerClusterer` constructor function.